# Como Ler este json com PHP

Tags: php, json

Como faço para ler esse arquivo JSON com PHP.

Tentei desta forma, porém não não funciona.

```
<?php

    $json_str = '{
    "numero":"1000",
    "log": {
        "message": "testing connection to the target URL",
        "level": "INFO",
        "time": "10:24:05"
    },
    "responsavel": {
        "nome":"Responsavel teste"
    }
}';

    $obj = json_decode($json_str);


    foreach ($obj as $objeto){

        echo "numero: ".$objeto->numero;

        foreach ($objeto as $item){

            echo "Mensagem: ".$item->message. " - ";
            echo "Nível: ".$item->level. "</br>";
        }

        foreach ($objeto as $responsavel){

            echo "NOME: ".$item->nome;

        }

    }


?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O json que apresentou não tem arrays é tudo objetos, por isso não fará sentido usar `foreach` para percorrer.

Para aceder aos campos que está a tentar aceder no código pode fazer assim:

```
echo "numero: ".$obj->numero;
echo "Mensagem: ".$obj->log->message. " - ";
echo "Nível: ".$obj->log->level. "</br>";
echo "NOME: ".$obj->responsavel->nome;
```

[Exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/xLDOJU)

Para conseguir usar os `foreachs` que tem no código, o json tinha que estar assim:

```
[{
    "numero": "1000",
    "log": [{
        "message": "testing connection to the target URL",
        "level": "INFO",
        "time": "10:24:05"
    }],
    "responsavel": [{
        "nome": "Responsavel teste"
    }]
}]
```

Repare como agora tem os `[` e `]` em cada para indicar que é um array  de objetos, que podemos agora percorrer com `foreach`.

O código para percorrer também tem ligeiramente ajustado que tinha alguns erros:

```
$obj = json_decode($json_str);

foreach ($obj as $objeto){

    echo "numero: ".$objeto->numero;

    foreach ($objeto->log as $item){ //faltava aqui $objeto->log

        echo "Mensagem: ".$item->message. " - ";
        echo "Nível: ".$item->level. "</br>";
    }

    foreach ($objeto->responsavel as $responsavel){ //faltava aqui $objeto->responsavel

        echo "NOME: ".$responsavel->nome;

    }

}
```

[Veja esta ultima versão também no Ideone](https://ideone.com/rEdjSA)

Answer (score 1):

Por padrão o `json_decode` retorna um `stdClass` e para seu acesso não é possível usar o `foreach`.

Por outro lado você pode fazer `json_decode` retornar um array, que por sua vez é iterável. Nesse arquivo em específico, talvez não valha e pena e usar como objeto sugerido [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/239952/4751) é mais simples:

```
$json_str = '{
    "numero":"1000",
    "log": {
        "message": "testing connection to the target URL",
        "level": "INFO",
        "time": "10:24:05"
    },
    "responsavel": {
        "nome":"Responsavel teste"
    }
}';

var_dump(json_decode($json_str, true);
```